# Firebase doesn't build on M1 simulator (Cannot find 'Analytics' in scope)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Since I have switched to M1, it has proven impossible running the app on the simulator. On the device itself it works fine.

I get the build error: `Cannot find 'Analytics' in scope`

```
import Firebase

class AlertService: AlertServiceBase, AlertServiceProtocol {

  func showWarningAlert(dict: NSDictionary) {
     ...
     Analytics.logEvent("blocked_no_more_warning", parameters: nil)
  }
}
```

I spoke to an Apple engineer and he said to change all Pods architecture to `Standard Architectures (arm64, armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)`.

It helped a bit to progress further, but then it failed on the firebase analytics issue. He suggested to post the issue here on SO. Hopefully someone had this before. Thanks

Comment: Did you try excluded architecture for simulator on M1? Go to Project (NOT TARGET) - Build Settings - Excluded Architectures - Debug - Any iOS Simulator SDK - arm64. You should repeat this for Main Project (and Pods Project if you use Pods).

Comment: Yes, I have followed your steps very carefully. I have made a bit of progress, now a different Pod caused this. It's the same issue. ```Could not find module 'KeychainAccess' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator``

Comment: I will add it as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project (NOT TARGET)

- Build Settings
- Excluded Architectures
- Debug -

Add a new setting called

```
Any iOS Simulator SDK - arm64
```

If you are using Pods, you should repeat above for your Pods PROJECT as well.

Some pod targets (like pod KeychainAccess in your case) might not be respecting what you had set at Pods PROJECT level, you might want to fix this exact same thing for offending Pod targets as well.

Or instead of checking all of the pod targets one by one, you could add this at the end of your podfile -

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

After doing this, do a `pod install` and a clean build, you should be good to go.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Thanks! I've been battling with this for almost 3 hrs and just manage to solve it!

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue only when debugging on a physical device, simulator worked fine.

Additional to the `import Firebase`, I had to `import FirebaseAnalytics`

Comment: Wow. That was much easier than previous fixes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Run `pod update` to update to a more recent Firebase version. Firebase fully supports the M1 simulator since about the 7.7.0 release.

Comment: Yes, the issue was that I had to delete the Derived Data. The issue with Firebase is now resolved. Only to be replaced with KeychainAccess (Pod). I get `Could not find module 'KeychainAccess' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator` So frustrating.